# Get the between time range from list of dates

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently want to get the date range (between time range) from the list of dates.

For example:

The time now is

> 2017-04-08 18:00

And I got these from and to dates:

```
public static string[] fromDates = new string[] { "2017-04-07 07:00", "2017-04-07 10:00", "2017-04-07 12:00", "2017-04-07 14:00", "2017-04-07 16:00" };
public static string[] toDates = new string[] { "2017-04-07 08:00", "2017-04-07 11:00", "2017-04-07 13:00", "2017-04-07 15:00", "2017-04-07 17:00" };
```

I am using this code:

```
public static bool IsInRange(this DateTime dateToCheck, string[] startDates, string[] endDates, out string StartDate, out string EndDate)
    {
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime();

        bool isWithinRange = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < startDates.Length; i++)
        {
            startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(startDates[i]);

            isWithinRange = dateToCheck >= startDate;

            if (isWithinRange)
                break;
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < endDates.Length; y++)
        {
            endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDates[y]);

            isWithinRange = dateToCheck < endDate;

            if (isWithinRange)
                break;
        }

        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;

        return isWithinRange;
    }
```

And I call it like this:

```
var isBetween = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-04-08 18:00").IsInRange(fromDates, toDates, out StartDate, out EndDate)
```

But I couldn't make it working, the `StartDate` in `IsInRange` method is always return true and it will return the first index from `fromDates` variable, which is wrong.

How can I make it like the time between?

I know I can do it like this:

```
var isBetween = dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck < endDate
```

But it is only one date need to check, what about if it is like my situation?

Your answer much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with yoir design, then you should simply do everything inside one loop, instead of doing it twice, as you want always to match first element with first element, second with second etc.

```
public static bool IsInRange(this DateTime dateToCheck, string[] startDates, string[] endDates, out DateTime StartDate, out DateTime EndDate)
    {
        if (startDates.Length != endDates.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The arrays must have the same length");
        }
        StartDate = new DateTime();
        EndDate = new DateTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < startDates.Length; i++)
        {
            StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(startDates[i]);
            EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDates[i]);

            if (dateToCheck >= StartDate && dateToCheck <= EndDate)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But as already stated in other answer - you should redesign your code, because it's not very maintenable and easy to understand

Comment: I was about to post these exact changes :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion @Pawel Gradecki, I would like to accept both of your answer, but they are (stackoverflow) not allowed me to do so :) . Will try Jon Skeet 's suggestion and yours on re-design my code.

Comment: Note that the code won't compile at the moment - the `return` statement needs to be *after* the loop. I would suggest that you don't need `isWithinRange` at all though - you can just return `true` instead of the `break` statement, and `return false` if you reach the end of the loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I messed something up when I fixed the formatting :/ Obviously the must be a return statement after the loop. I fixed the code now.

Answer (score 4):

I would start by converting everything into a more useful object model:

- Get rid of all the strings (i.e. convert from strings to something more useful early on)
- Instead of having two collections, create a new type indicating "a date/time range". You're being somewhat foiled by relating the wrong items together: the start values aren't related to each other, they're related to their corresponding end dates.

You could do this within the method if you really need to, but it would be better to move to a richer object model for as much of your code as you can. For example, suppose you have:

```
public sealed class DateTimeRange
{
    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime End { get; }

    public DateTimeRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        // TODO: Validate that start <= end
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public bool Contains(DateTime value) => Start <= value && value < End;
}
```

Then your method can look like this:

```
public DateTimeRange FindRange(IEnumerable<DateTimeRange> ranges, DateTime value) =>
    ranges.FirstOrDefault(range => range.Contains(value));
```

That will return `null` if no ranges contain the value, or the first one that *does* contain a value otherwise.

(As an aside, I'd do all of this in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) instead as a better date/time API, but I'm biased.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Jon Skeet, I would like to accept both of your answer, but they are (stackoverflow) not allowed me to do so :) . Will try to re-design my code as your suggestion